# Network share to all computers in the domain is public

Tags: networking, active-directory, share

I'm managing a domain network, Recently I found out that when ever any user is accessing a computer through network share, example:

\computer\c$

He can view everything with not need of credentials. I'm looking to enable the need of credentials to access not public shares in computers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This share, `\\COMPUTER\c$`, is one of the **Administrative shares** created automatically by the system. These shares cannot be accessed by users without administrative privileges, so there should not be the problem you described. (Have you actually tested this on a normal user?)

Administrative shares can't be permanently removed, but they can be disabled:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters]
"AutoShareWks"=dword:00000000
```

However, you  probably shouldn't do that, because it may [cause problems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/842715/overview-of-problems-that-may-occur-when-administrative-shares-are-missing).

Also, your users won't have permissions to everything through any share without also having NTFS permissions. Even Domain Administrators can't access user's home folder through an administrative share because by default there is no NTFS permissions for that.

> [Share and NTFS Permissions on a File Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754178(v=ws.11).aspx)
>
> Access to a folder on a file server can be determined through two sets
>   of permission entries: the share permissions set on a folder and the
>   NTFS permissions set on the folder (which can also be set on files).
>   Share permissions are often used for managing computers with FAT32
>   file systems, or other computers that do not use the NTFS file system.
>
> Share permissions and NTFS permissions are independent in the sense
>   that neither changes the other. The final access permissions on a
>   shared folder are determined by taking into consideration both the
>   share permission and the NTFS permission entries. The more restrictive
>   permissions are then applied.

Comment: Thank you! The user I used to access with to the network share, was domain admin.